# Error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React-Redux and this is my slice -

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const balanceSlice = createSlice({
  name: "balance",
  initialState: {
    value: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value += 10000;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 10000;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement } = balanceSlice.actions;

export const selectCount = (state) => state.balance.value;

export default balanceSlice.reducer;
```

In the browser, I get this error - **TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**
This error points to the second last line.
What I see is `balance` is defined, then why does this throw error?

*Point to be noted that in the Chrome Redux Devtools there is a state for `counter` not `balance` as I have defined.*

Comment: Please edit the question to add some logging and show what you are observing at each line.  You should also say something about what you're doing to run this code and reproduce the issue.

Comment: where do you want me to add log?

Comment: check the state value inside the `selectCount` method. As per the error, balance is not defined in the state.

Comment: doesn't the name:"balance" explain which state are we trying to access

Answer (score 0):

Is `balanceSlice` your only reducer, or are you using `combineReducers` to combine it with other reducers?

This error is indicating that your state does not have a top-level property called `balance`.  So these are the possibilities:

1 ) you have a bunch of reducers nested in way where `balance` isn't at the top level

2 ) you assigned this reducer to a different key name when combining (`counter`?)

3 ) this reducer is your entire state in which case there is no `balance` property because the entire state is the balance.

If it's #1, you need to figure out the path to this slice in your state.

If it's #2, fix your `combineReducers`.

If it's #3, change your selector to `(state) => state.value`.

> Point to be noted that in the Chrome Redux Devtools there is a state for counter not balance as I have defined.

I'm pretty sure it's #2. I think you copied a `combineReducers` from the documentation without understanding what it's doing.

Does your reducer look like this?

```
import balanceReducer from "./reducer"
// ^ or whatever you called it

const reducer = combineReducers({
  counter: balanceReducer,
})
```

The combine reducers function takes a key-value object of reducers.  The key (which is `counter`) becomes the name of the property in the `state` and the value is the reducer for that property.  You want your property to be called `balance`, so we need to assign it to the `balance` key.  This key is what matters, **not** the slice name, though usually they are the same.

```
import balanceReducer from "./reducer"

const reducer = combineReducers({
  balance: balanceReducer,
})
```